# Passing around generic objects using an interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm building a tool to simply the exporting to excel for later re-use. One of the issues I'm running into is an easy, and reliable way of passing around an object that contains my cell data.

The class that contains my cell data looks like:

```
public interface IExcelCell { 

}

public class ExcelCell<T> : IExcelCell
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using it like so:

```
private void GenerateCell(IExcelCell cell, int currentColumn)
{
    // check type of Value, apply optional formatting
}
```

---

Essentially what I need to do is check if the incoming data is of a certain data-type, e.g. string, double, DateTime. Is there a convenient way of doing this?

**Edit**

This is the relevant exportation code to illustrate somewhat of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class ExcelExporter
{
    private ExcelPackage excelPackage;
    private OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet;
    private int currentRow;

    public ExcelPackage ExportExcelWorkbook(ExcelWorkbook workbook)
    {
        excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
        GenerateWorkbook(workbook);

        return excelPackage;
    }

    private void GenerateWorkbook(ExcelWorkbook workbook)
    {
        foreach (var worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            GenerateWorksheet(worksheet);
        }
    }

    private void GenerateWorksheet(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
    {
        currentWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet.Name);
        currentRow = 1;

        foreach (var section in worksheet.Sections)
        {
            GenerateSection(section);
        }

    }

    private void GenerateSection(ExcelSection section)
    {
        if (!section.Name.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = section.Name;
            currentRow++;
        }

        if (section.Headers != null && section.Headers.Any())
        {
            GenerateHeaders(section.Headers);
            currentRow++;
        }

        foreach (var row in section.Rows)
        {
            GenerateRow(row);
            currentRow++;
        }
    }

    private void GenerateHeaders(IEnumerable<string> headers)
    {
        var enumerable = headers as IList<string> ?? headers.ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < enumerable.Count(); i++)
        {
            currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, i + 1].Value = enumerable[i];
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRow(ExcelRow row)
    {
        var currentColumn = 0;

        foreach (var cell in row.RowData)
        {
            GenerateCell(cell, currentColumn);
            currentColumn++;
        }
    }

    private void GenerateCell(IExcelCell cell, int currentColumn)
    {
        var excelCell = (ExcelCell<object>) cell;

        if (excelCell.Value is DateTime)
        {
            currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
        }

        currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn].Value = excelCell.Value;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Taking Gilad's advice from his answer, I came up with a slightly different solution:

```
// interface
public interface IExcelCell { 
    object Value { get; set; }
    string NumberFormat { get; }
}

// implementation
public class ExcelCell : IExcelCell
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string NumberFormat => null;
}

public class DateTimeExcelCell : IExcelCell
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string NumberFormat => "mm/dd/yyyy";
}

// Cell generation
private void GenerateCell(IExcelCell cell, int currentColumn)
{
    if (cell.NumberFormat != null)
    {
        currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn].Style.Numberformat.Format = cell.NumberFormat;
    }

    currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn].Value = cell.Value;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like `if (call is DateTime)`?

Comment: What is your objective after knowing the data type?

Comment: @DiskJunky Somewhat, but what it would actually look like is something like `if (((ExcelCell<object>) cell).Value is DateTime)`. This just seems to be a bit convoluted, and I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Declare the interface as `IExcelCell<T>`.

Comment: You could use `cell.Value.GetType()` if that's the case

Comment: @SunilSinghal I'm going to be applying optional formatting to the cell once I know the datatype.

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? There are already several libraries for generating Excel files: EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, Aspose, Office XML SDK etc.

Comment: @mason This is for a generic reporting system, and we're using Office XML SDK to do the actual exporting. We just need something to reliably shape our data and export it.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this. If you want to create an adapter between your project and Office XML SDK, then your adapter probably shouldn't leak implementation details like Cells. Just have it accept a strongly typed object describing the data to be exported, and then use the sdk to generate the file.

Comment: @mason ah, after digging in to our code, it turns out we're using EPPlus, the namespaces got my switched around. I'm merely building on top of the EPPlus functionality we already have implemented.

Comment: I still don't get why you're building Excel functionality on top of EPPlus. You're leaking implementation details. The code calling this doesn't need to know about Excel specific things like Cells. That's a violation of separation of concerns. Your adapter should accept an object that describes the data to be exported, and returns the Excel file as a byte array or memory stream etc.

Comment: This is a portion of the adapter that handles the transformation of the objects. This is just making certain portions nearly overly generic in order to simplify the extraction of data. The actual objects have no real concept of the transformations being applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155849/discussion-between-jd-davis-and-mason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Seeing updated question:**

As I suggested bellow use the `is` operator on `cell`:

```
if (cell is ExcelCell<DateTime>)
{
    currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
}
```

*But still see answer below about the Factory pattern part*

---

**Original answer:**

I guess cleanest will be to declare the interface as generic and have the `Value` in it. If not then you can use the `is` operator. For example:

```
IExcelCell cell = new ExcelCell<DateTime>();
bool result1 = cell is ExcelCell<DateTime>; // true
bool result2 = cell is ExcelCell<int>; // false
```

So in your function:

```
private void GenerateCell(IExcelCell cell, int currentColumn)
{
    if(cell is ExcelCell<DateTime>)
    {
    }
}
```

Or the `as` operator if you want to use it:

```
private void GenerateCell(IExcelCell cell, int currentColumn)
{
    var c = cell as ExcelCell<DateTime>
    if(c != null)
    {
        // TODO - use casted c
    }
}
```

---

From your comments it seems like the purpose of knowing the type is to perform formatting. I suggest that instead have a Factory pattern that given a specific type formats that specific type. Or if you change the interface then something like:

```
public interface IExcelCell<T> 
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeExcelCell : IExcelCell<DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // TODO - formatting you want for DateTime
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not sure how the my `GenerateCell` method signature would be affected by switching to the factory pattern.

Comment: @JDDavis - I didn't explain in the answer how to implement it that way because it is a bit more I think it is best to read about the design pattern first.

Comment: However, I am still afraid that the factory pattern wouldn't quite work. I'm not quite setting the formatting on the data, but rather the cell. I may be able to get something to work though.

Comment: @JDDavis - true :) It was mainly for the beginning before you updated the rest. Can still work but happy the suggestion above was good for you